# Use Variable from for function in another js file

Tags: json, function, var

i want to use a variable from an other js file but when i use the import and export statement that dont work because that say {file} is not defined.
And my problem is my variable is in a function, and in a loop for.
i think i'm doing it wrong but could you help me ?

here is the code on my fabric.js

```
    const initCanvas = () => (                                  
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        preserveObjectStacking:true,
        height: 450,
        width: 600,
        backgroundImage: {file}, <--- i want to use the variable "file" here 
        
    })
)
```

and in my emil.js i have a function with this code

```
  DisplayCategory(category) {  
       (...)             //Function that generate te list of 
    else {                                          //Generate the product list of a category (ex : product[2][x])
        let product = [];
        let x = findProduct(product_array, selected_product);
        for (let y = 1; product_array[x][y]; y++) {
            var ext = ".jpg";
            var file = '/' + product_array[x][y] + ext; <--- file is defined here
            product.push(
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} className={this.takeClass(product_array[x][y])} onClick={() => this.HandleOnClick(product_array[x][y], 2)}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={file} /> <--- and is used here
```

The function is to long so i dont have put the rest

Comment: You can't - at least not in this way. Variables are local to the scope they're declared in. All hell would break loose if they leaked out into the global scope everywhere. You say you had problems with import/export but don't show that. I'd post that up as a separate question and detail what issue you faced.

Comment: Ok thanks and if i defined "ext" and "file" at the top level and i use "this" ? that could work ?

Comment: If your scripts share a common namespace (an object declared on `window`) then, yes, they could share data that way. It's common to have a global namespace, say `myProject` on `window`, which is the only thing you write globally, and under which everything lives.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. i dont know how to resolve my problem but i continue to search ^^

Comment: See answer.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common pattern is to have a common namespace, an object, written to `window`. That way your project writes only a single thing to the global namespace, and everything lives under there.

This is an easy way to share data between scripts.

Let's say we have bootstrap.js, which does this:

```
window.someNamespace = {};
```

Then in another script, you have this:

```
someNamespace.sharedProperty = 'foo';
alert('This script can call @sharedProperty -'+someNamespace.sharedProperty);
```

Then in yet another script, you can read that property too:

```
console.log(someNamespace.sharedProperty);
```

...because everything (or at least everything that needs to be shared - everything else should remain localised within closures) lives under `window.someNamespace`.

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept if an answer helps you.